# Weird template rendering behavior with Django and links <a>

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I noticed that when i input a link into for loop in my templates that it gets injected into the first, lower elements. Il illustrate it below:

Base template:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

template which extends Base template

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}
{% block content %}
{% if elem_list %}
<ul>
{for elem in elem_list}
<li> <a class="bob" href="">

<div class="div1">
<div class="subdiv"></div>
</div>
<div class="div2">
<div class="subdiv"></div>
</div>
</a> </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

and the output i get on my page

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<ul>
<a class="bob" href="">
<li> <a class="bob" href="">

<div class="div1">
<a class="bob" href=""></a>
<div class="subdiv"><a class="bob" href=""></a></div>
<div class="subdiv"></div>
</div>
<div class="div2">
<a class="bob" href=""></a>
<div class="subdiv"><a class="bob" href=""></a></div>
<div class="subdiv"></div>
</div>

</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this some kind of feature Django has? How can i stop it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing at all to do with Django.

Your HTML is invalid, since an inline element like `a` cannot contain a block element like `div`.

You are presumably viewing the generated HTML via your browser's developer tools, which is doing its very best to interpret your broken HTML.